# Repeated column in mapping for entry error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am doing a simple hibernate program in which I use Attribute override and Embedded object keys and I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated
>   column in mapping for entity: com.hibernate.Model.Employee column:
>   pincode (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

**Employee.java**

```
package com.hibernate.Model;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  LastName;
    private String  email;
    private String  phoneNo;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride (name="City" ,   column=@Column(name="OFFICE_CITY")),
    @AttributeOverride (name="State",   column=@Column(name="OFFICE_STATE")),
    @AttributeOverride (name="Country", column=@Column(name="OFFICE_COUNTRY")),
    @AttributeOverride (name="pinCode", column=@Column(name="OFFICE_PINCODE"))})
    private Address  officeAddress;

    @Embedded
    private Address  homeAddress;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
    public Address getOfficeAddress() {
        return officeAddress;
    }
    public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
        this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
    }
    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }
    public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
package com.hibernate.Model;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String City;
    private String State;
    private String Country;
    private String pincode;
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }
    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }



}
```

**Hibernate.jsp**

```
package com.hibernate.Test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.Model.Address;
import com.hibernate.Model.Employee;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp = new Employee();

        Address addr=new Address();

        emp.setFirstName("Vikas");
        emp.setLastName("Bhardwaj");
        emp.setEmail("bhardwajvikas93@gmail.com");
        emp.setPhoneNo("9741178304");

        addr.setCity("MEHRE");
        addr.setCountry("INDIA");
        addr.setState("HIMACHAL");
        addr.setPincode("174305");

        emp.setHomeAddress(addr);

        Address addr2 = new Address();
        addr2.setCity("Bangalore");
        addr2.setCountry("INDIA");
        addr2.setState("KARNATKA");
        addr2.setPincode("560008");

        emp.setOfficeAddress(addr2);

        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session ssn = sf.openSession();
        ssn.beginTransaction();
        ssn.save(emp);
        ssn.getTransaction().commit();
        ssn.close();
    }
}
```

**cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateDb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">vikas</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.Model.Employee"/>
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.Model.Address"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

In this program by embedable, I am printing both member variables in one table.

The task is with address class, I am printing two addresses. One is for home address and one is for office address by using AttributeOverrides but it gives me the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a valid property name `pincode`

```
@AttributeOverride (name="pinCode", column=@Column(name="OFFICE_PINCODE"))
```

need to change to

```
@AttributeOverride (name="pincode", column=@Column(name="OFFICE_PINCODE"))
```

Try to specify `@AttributeOverrides` for `homeAddress`, if it will not help.